# Python Parallel Issues

Tags: python, parallel-processing

My program is set up to download a Cartesian product of URLs based on state and other variables, save the zip files (from the URLs created) to a specified location, check the zip file for data (some zip files download without data), write to a specific file regarding the status that states data and then write to a file when the state is complete. This is done in parallel based on state i.e., Alabama and Alaska will do the above in parallel. However, I keep getting the following error:

```
An unexpected error occurred while tokenizing input
The following traceback may be corrupted or invalid
The error message is: ('EOF in multi-line statement', (179, 0))
```

The error occurs when I start fresh i.e., haven't run the process before. If I partial run the process then start over this does not occur. More specifically it happen randomly.

Here is my code:

Functions -

```
def createURL(state, typ, geography, level, data, dictionary):

    DATALIST    = list(itertools.product(typ, geography, level, data))
    TXTLIST     = list(itertools.product(typ, dictionary))
    DEFLIST     = list(itertools.product(typ))

    DATALINKS = []
    for data in DATALIST:
        result  = 'URL'

    DATALINKS.append(result)

     TXTLINKS = []
     for txt in TXTLIST:
          links = 'URL'
    TXTLINKS.append(links)


     DEFLINKS = []
     for defl in DEFLIST:
         definitions = 'URL'

    DEFLINKS.append(definitions)

      URLLINKS = DATALINKS + TXTLINKS + DEFLINKS
      return URLLINKS


def downloadData(state, TYPE, GEOGRAPHY, LEVEL, DATA, \
             DICTIONARY, YEAR, QUARTER, completedStates):
     print ('Working on state: ', state)    

     URLLINKS = createURL(state, TYPE, GEOGRAPHY, LEVEL, DATA, DICTIONARY)

    DIRECTORY   = '/home/justin/QWI/' + YEAR + 'Q' + QUARTER + '/' + state
    if not os.path.exists(DIRECTORY[:-2]):
         os.makedirs(DIRECTORY[:-2])

    if not os.path.exists(DIRECTORY):
         os.makedirs(DIRECTORY)

    downLoadedURLs = DIRECTORY[:-2] + 'downLoadedURLs.txt'
    if not os.path.isfile(downLoadedURLs):
         with open(downLoadedURLs, 'a') as downloaded:
             downloaded.write('')


     with open(downLoadedURLs) as downloaded:
         URLcontent = downloaded.read().splitlines()


     URLLINKS = [x for x in URLLINKS if x not in URLcontent]

    for url in URLLINKS:
         print ('Downloading data: ', url)
         save = DIRECTORY + '/' + os.path.basename(url)

        urllib.urlretrieve(url, save)
        with open(downLoadedURLs, 'a') as downloaded:
             downloaded.write('{}\n'.format(url))

        if os.stat(save).st_size == 0:
            shutil.rmtree(DIRECTORY)
             with open(DIRECTORY[:-2] + '/zeroDataStates.txt', 'a') as zeroData:
            zeroData.write('{}\n'.format(state))
        break

    with open(completedStates, 'a') as completedState:
        completedState.write('{}\n'.format(state))
```

Here is the parallel code:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

STATE = ['al', 'ak', etc...]

Parallel(n_jobs = CORES)(delayed(downloadData)\
    (state, TYPE, GEOGRAPHY, LEVEL, DATA, DICTIONARY, YEAR, QUARTER, 
    completedStates) for state in STATE)
```

I believe the error is occurring either when writing to a file or acquiring the URLs.

Answer (score 0):

```
'EOF in multi-line statement'
```

A Python multi-line statement is one that ends in a `\`. `EOF` means the end of the file. So you're looking for a multi-line statement that isn't finished before the end of the file. Your example code contains exactly that on the first line of this snippet:

```
Parallel(n_jobs = CORES)(delayed(downloadData)\
    (state, TYPE, GEOGRAPHY, LEVEL, DATA, DICTIONARY, YEAR, QUARTER, 
    completedStates) for state in STATE)
```

It looks like the brackets will parse across lines unambiguously so you should be able to just delete the rogue `\`. You might want to check your formatting though. The formatting doesn't give any clues about the structure of the code.

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, that did not fix the issue as I still got the above error randomly i.e., 1 out of 4 times. I switched the way I parallelized the code to the UNIX command line e.g., I pass in the states via the command line and run the program in parallel from there.

Comment: So you probably have another multi-line statement near the end of a file. Search your code for ```\```.